# How can I make my site mobile friendly? Or write a mobile mode for it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mobile-website

I am creating a website with React and I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Do I need to write special css codes to make my website more mobile friendly? I tried using "%" method but that did not seem to work. Or do I need to write seperate .js and .css files just for my sites mobile mode? What would be your advice to me?

Comment: you must write specific CSS with media queries that targets small screens

Comment: you should design your project separate from react with some mobile first library like tailwind or bootstrap these libraries have most of work done for mobile friendly design to speed up your project then after design is done break them into react components it will save you from lots of hassel

Comment: Thank you so much this question was messing with me for a long time I will search tailwind and bootstrap for more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "mobile friendly" website, you must mean **responsive** website. I would suggest using Bootstrap framework for this modern need: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

You definitely need to learn about the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

You could use your own CSS, but a framework is likely to regroup a whole set of tools you may need in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your great guidance! I will study about these right away. For the last few weeks I was just looking for an efficient way to create a responsive website. With these sources I won't waste any more time.